# git clone without certificates using chef git resource

Tags: git, chef-infra

I want to clone my git repo with `chef git resource`. I don't want to use ssh keys for authentication.
From the terminal I can simply do this

`GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://url`
 or

```
$git config --global http.sslVerify false  
$git clone https://url
```

How can achieve the same with chef `git resource`?

Comment: `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true` and `http.sslVerify=false` stop SSL certificate verification from happening during requests. If the https certificate expires or the certificate authority signing the request is unknown the request would normally fail. Generally this is a good thing to keep on. These options do not control authentication, which you wouldn't be doing with `ssh` keys for a `https` address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
ENV['GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY']=true

git "target directory" do
 repository "https:/url"
 revision master
 action :checkout
end
```

You can set any environment variable in a recipe via the `ENV[]` hash.
You may wish to use `action :sync` to keep the target in sync with the repo.

Doc: [Git resource documentation](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/resources.html#git)

Comment: You have to be careful when mixing Ruby code into the base recipe's like this. There are two distinct phases to a Chef client run. Resource compilation, where your entire recipe is read/executed. Then applying the compiled list of resources comes after this. Say you were to change the environment back later in the recipe, logically you would think that will happen after the resource. In actual fact the entire recipe has been read/executed before any resources are actually applied so your environment would be in the later state when the resources are applied.

Comment: I did not wish to enter this details in this answer to keep it simple. Git resource do not take an env argument. À workaround would be a ruby block to define the env and the git resource. But there's also two execute or managing the git config by Chef too. Well plenty of other ways around.